# Memory usage of java program is quite different between VisualVm profiling result and Linux top statis

Tags: java, linux, memory, profiling

I have a java program running in below memory parameters on a centos7 64bit box(total 512Mb memory):

```
-Xms80M
-Xmx128M
-XX:MaxPermSize=64M
-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=32M
```

from the jvisualvm profile I can see its memory usage is max 130M (max used heap + max used Perm), but from the linux pmap command or top command it says it used about 310M, which occupy most of my server physical memory:

```
KiB Mem :   500840 total,     7700 free,   354256 used,   138884 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used.   109924 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16844 root      20   0 1017504 311272  10388 S  0.7 62.1   4:43.65 java
```

I would like to know why the drastic different between pmap(top) statistics and my profiling result, and which is accurate?